# Send HttpListenerRequest to another website

Tags: c#, http, httprequest

I am trying to forward the http request that I receive to another website, so here is how I receive data

```cs
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:3294/discord/");
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    //here is want to send data to https://www.discord.com/api/webhooks/#################/###########
}
```

to send data I use `HttpClient.PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)` but I can't send `context.Request` as `HttpContent` :(

I hope I gave enough information.

Comment: Don't p[ut the send into a While loop.  What error do you get?  Test failed line of code by itself and get working before you try along with a listener.

Comment: @jdweng there is no error, I receive the data, but I am trying to send it to another website, how can I do that?

Comment: The data is either in the body or an attachment.  Looks like you are trying to use body. to create a new Request (You are using lIstnerRequest which is wrong); you need a post and set the Context Length of body.

Comment: can you please send me a tutorial link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code would look something like this:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:3294/discord/");
listener.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

Stream body = context.Request.InputStream;
Encoding encoding = context.Request.ContentEncoding;
byte[] buffer = new byte[body.Length];
body.Read(buffer,0,(int)body.Length);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("https://www.discord.com/api/webhooks/#################/###########");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = context.Response.ContentType;

body.Position = 0;
request.ContentLength = body.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
HttpWebResponse response =  (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: 'This stream does not support seek operations.`
at `byte[] buffer = new byte[body.Length];`
what is this due to?

Comment: the exception doesn't make sense on line you posted.  I added one line of code : body.Position = 0;  I is possible the body doesn't contain data.

Comment: thanks for the help, I will try find out the reason for this error :)